First step in Rudin's proof of the uniqueness of Haar measures.
This question is about Rudin's proof of uniqueness of Haar measures in 'Fourier Analysis on Groups'.
The proof I'm talking about is the exact same one discussed in this post.
The context is that we have an LCA group $G$ with two Haar measures $m$ and $m'$. The statement is that $m' = \lambda m$ for some $\lambda > 0$. The proof starts by fixing $g \in C_c(G)$ such that
$$
\int_G g \ dm = 1.
$$
Why does such a $g$ exist? At first I thought it looked like a consequence of some formulation of Riesz' representation theorem. However, neither the formulation of Riesz' representation theorem in the Appendix of the book nor the versions I could find on the internet lead me to see how we get the existence.

Take any nonzero function $h\in C_c(G).$ Let $f=|h|.$ Then $\int f,dm>0.$ Thus $g=cf$ satisfies $\int g,dm=1$ for a positive constant $c.$

@RyszardSzwarc Oh, I see. But how do we know a non-zero $h \in C_c(G)$ exists?

Take any open set $U$ with compact closure. Then $h=1_U*1_U$ is continuous and has compact support. Moreover $h\ge 0$ and $\int h,dm=m(U)^2>0.$

Let $x\in G$. Since $G$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space there exists $f\in C_{c}(G)$ with $f\geq 0$ and $f(x) = 1$ by a variation of Urysohn's lemma. To show $\int_{G} f \, dm > 0$, note that by continuity there exists an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ such that $f(y)\geq 1/2$ for all $y\in U$. Then $f \geq (1/2) \mathbb{1}_{U}$. Since the result 1.1.2. in Rudin's book states that $m(U) > 0$, it follows that
\begin{equation}
\int_{G} f \, dm \geq \tfrac{1}{2} m(U) > 0.
\end{equation}
Now define $g := ( \int_{G} f \, dm )^{-1}f$. Then $g\in C_{c}(G)$ and $\int_{G} g \, dm = 1$, so $g$ has the desired properties.
